# Heroku Free Tier giving error "Free quota exhausted" despite having used only 5 hours

Tags: heroku

I've just recently deployed a small app to my Heroku account. However, after about 5 hours of uptime my app stopped serving. The Heroku app log printed out those lines:

```
2018-10-26T10:29:04.037480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H82 desc="Free 
app running time quota exhausted" method=POST path="/webhook" 
host=(my-app-url) request_id=(some-id) fwd="some-ip" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=https
```

The problem is, running heroku ps yielded this output:

```
~$ heroku ps -a (my-app-name)
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 994h 30m (99%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 5h 29m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping
```

I even checked my other apps, they are all functioning. I also tried restart all my dynos, switch on/off the maintenance mode, but the problem still persists.

Is there anything I can do other than to wait until the next month and see if my quota resets?

Comment: Sounds like a question for Heroku support.

Comment: Yeah I tried to contact them, but they do not receive support ticket from Free Tier Accounts, and specifically say that I must go up here to have my question answered

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I am facing the same issue

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. First my apps used all of the 1,000 free hours in just 5 days, even though previously we never reached the 1,000 hours in the *entire month*, and then when I transferred the apps to another account which had 1,000 free hours, they worked for one day and stopped, even though I still have 950+ free hours left.